# Google Drive API - Get change type

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get the type of change associated with a file change on the Google Drive (type of change = modified|renamed).

I'm currently getting the file changes via the [change collection](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-changes). Therefore I know, that the attached file was changed, but not exactly how => **I can't distinguish between a file rename and a file modified**.

Is there a way, in which I can identify that only the file name changed and not the content without tracking the file changes myself (keeping a list with file ids to names correlations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google API doesn't return what the change is. I've had instances where opening a file triggered a change as the last_viewed_at was updated and all I could do was compare the current state with what was stored in my DB.

See [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-changes) where it's stated:

> A change does not provide a delta between revisions. Applications that
>   need to know which properties have changed should persist the
>   previously known state of the item and compare.