# Google API drive.changes.list gives empty array of changes

Tags: node.js, google-api

I'm using the drive.changes apis to request for a list of changes by getting startPageToken first and then request with changes.list api as follows.

```
const drive = google.drive("v3");
    console.log("Authentication successful");
    const start = await drive.changes.getStartPageToken({
        auth: oauth2Client,
    });

    console.log("start response is ", start.data.startPageToken);

    const changes = await drive.changes.list({
        auth: oauth2Client,

        pageToken: start.data.startPageToken,
    });
    console.log("changes are ", changes.data);
    return changes.data.changes;
};
```

However, the changes I get back are the following despite I have made changes to the file (I used the drive watch api for listener for changes and pin me via webhook whenever changes occur, and I only request for changes.list whenever a change occurs)

```
changes are  { kind: 'drive#changeList', newStartPageToken: '433', changes: [] }
```

I tested by signing into the drive and changing the title of a file under the drive, then my webhook gets pin from google that something changed so I send this changes.list request, but it still returns the empty array of changes. I'm expecting the changes to look something more like this:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#changeList",
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "newStartPageToken": string,
  "changes": [
    changes Resource
  ]
}
```

Comment: I believe you can't find out what kind of change happened... see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57427647/google-drive-api-get-change-type

Answer (score 0):

`getStartPageToken` gets future start page token, so you have to make changes after execute `getStartPageToken` to get changes.
You'll always get empty changes if you use `changes.list` soon after `getStartPageToken`.

Comment: This makes no sense... he is starting the token from page 1... the problem is that the changes array is empty.